# Bash script to delete text from Tripwire's pol file to get rid of false negatives

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I currently am trying to write a bash script with sed that will delete the settings in Tripwire's file twpol.txt file. If anyone knows how that'd be great or if you could let me know if someone has done something like it that'd be helpful as well because right now I'm getting over 200 lines of false negative error reports.

I've already tried something like:

```
sed -i -d "/usr/sbin/fixrmtab"
```

Comment: can you post your input file? And that could work `sed -i "/\/usr\/sbin\/fixrmtab/d"`

Comment: Can you show your sample input and expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete lines containing `/usr/sbin/fixrmtab`:

```
sed -i '/usr\/sbin\/fixrmtab/d' twpol.txt
```